# Abelian group such that $x+x=0$

Tags: vector-spaces

If $G$ is an abelian group such that $x+x=0$ $\forall x \in G$ then $G$ has a natural vector space structure over $\mathbb F_2$, How can i prove this? Ofcourse if $G$ is $\mathbb F_2$ then it is trivially true. Please help.

Comment: Isn't $G$ just isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$? Any field is a vector space over itself.

Comment: No, $\mathbb{F}_2\times\mathbb{F}_2$ satisfies it too.

Comment: Multiplication by $0\in\mathbb{F}_2$ gives the zero of the group. Multiplication by $1\in\mathbb{F}_2$ gives you the same element of the group. Now, check the properties of vector space.

Comment: The only interesting property is $\alpha x+\beta x=(\alpha+\beta)x$ for $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{F}_2$ and $x$ in the group.

Comment: Interestingly, it's unnecessary to say that the group is abelian: $ab=(bb)ab(aa)=b(ba)(ba)a=ba$

Answer (score 2):

Any abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module via the action
$$
(k,x) \mapsto kx, \quad k\in \mathbb{Z}, x\in G
$$
The idea here is that this action descends to one from $\mathbb{Z}_2$

Consider $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{[0], [1]\}$. You just need to check that the map
$$
([r],x) \mapsto rx\quad \text{ from } \quad\mathbb{F}_2\times G\to G
$$
is well-defined and satisfies the axioms of a vector space.

The key part of the argument here is well-definedness : If $r_1 \equiv r_2$, then $r_1 = r_2 + 2k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$, so for any $x\in G$
$$
r_1x = r_2x + 2kx = r_2x + k(x+x) = r_2x
$$

Hence, the action is well-defined, and it obviously satisfies the axioms of a vector space.